# Homebrew pip issue 5599 on Intel macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, homebrew-cask

(I'm new here, so please be gentle)
When using topgrade in homebrew (I installed topgrade after installing homebrew with `brew install topgrade`) on macOS big sur on a 2020 Intel 13" default upper specs MacBook Pro I ran into the following issue:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Looking for a solution on the web I found: https://andreaolivato.medium.com/how-to-solve-the-invalid-active-developer-path-brew-error-after-updating-to-mac-os-catalina-10-15-e351e743dd23

Following the advice I ran: `xcode-select --install` and restarted afterwards.

After running topgrade again I became a bit suspicious when it said:

```
    ...
Successfully installed pip-21.1.1
    WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.1.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    ...
```

but I though well, seems like it updated itself. So I ran topgrade again and it said

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (21.1.1)
```

Since then I've been getting the same answer. I followed the link but found no solution other than the python workaround, which seems to be a short term solution. As far as I now have both pip version 19.2.3 as well as 21.1.1 and need to remove the old one right? But how do I do that?
And does `Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (21.1.1)` mean it already fixed itself? And what happens if I ignore the problem? If anyone could help me out it would really be appreciated. While I love tech I've got no coding experience at all in this is just over my head.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but a systems question; you'll have better luck asking over on sister site superuser.com.

Comment: Ok, will do, thank you so much!